# Predict decay chain of a radioactive element

Tags: nuclear-physics, radioactivity

I know there are tables of decay chain of radioactive elements. Is there a way to predict the whole chain from the first radioactive element?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Evaluated Nuclear Structure Data File](http://www.nndc.bnl.gov/ensdf/); search "by decay" and put the nuclide you'd like to start with in "parent."  This will also tell you half-lives and Q-values.

A few nuclides have multiple decay modes; for instance radon-221 usually beta-decays to francium-221, but alpha-decays to polonium-217 about 22% of the time.  You may find other "forks in the road" depending on where you start.

You ask in a comment about U-235.  You can go a little simpler by looking at the [chart of nuclides](http://www.nndc.bnl.gov/chart), which lists decay modes:

- U-235: α
- Th-231: β
- Pa-231: α
- Ac-227: β 99% (neglect α 1%)
- Th-227: α
- Ra-223: α
- Ra-219: α
- Po-215: α
- Pb-211: β
- Bi-211: α 99.3% (neglect β 0.7%)
- Tl-207: β

That takes you to lead-207, which is stable (and makes up 22% of natural lead).

Comment: hey thanks for the reply

I understand there are table we can look up with the decay chains, but have we been able to model and predict sequence?

Comment: Modern nuclear models are able to predict the energy levels for different nuclides, and that tells you which decays are energetically allowed.  In general nuclei with "too many" neutrons will $\beta^-$-decay, nuclei with "too few" neutrons will $\beta^+$-decay, and nuclei that are "too heavy" will $\alpha$-decay.  However the details are nontrivial, especially in the no-mans-land of unstable nuclei between lead and thorium.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but are we able to predict the chain of decay say starting from the U-253 to Fe?