# Predicting a decay chain?

Tags: nuclear-physics

Is there a way to predict a decay chain? Let's say I have U-238 and want to find out its decay chain, is there a way to do that without looking it up? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate of Predict decay chain of a radioactive element : http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/217233

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Predict decay chain of a radioactive element](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/217233/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple way of predicting the decay chain for any nuclear decay.  There may be several alternative decay chains.  It is similar to the case of an excited atom returning to its ground state after it has been excited.  Predicting what "route" it takes depends on complicated quantum transition rules that tell you which transitions are allowed and their probabilities.